# ValueError when creating a Series

Tags: python, pandas

When I run:

```
ser = pd.Series ( data =[ 100, 'Ninguno', 300, 'Texto', 5.3], index =[ 'pablo', 'juan', 'pedro', 'enrique'])
ser
```

the result gives me error:

> ValueError: Length of passed values is 5, index implies 4.

Answer (score 0):

A pandas Series is just a list or array that has an index.  You are passing in the index and the data in your call above, but your index is not the same length as the data, so that is the problem.  Below, I have added another element to the index to show a successful creation.

From the look of your data, it isn't clear that you want to make a Series ?

```
In [2]: data = [100, 'Ninguno', 300, 'Texto', 5.3]                              

In [3]: index = [ 'pablo', 'juan', 'pedro', 'enrique', 'other']                 

In [4]: ser = pd.Series(data=data, index=index)                                 

In [5]: ser                                                                     
Out[5]: 
pablo          100
juan       Ninguno
pedro          300
enrique      Texto
other          5.3
dtype: object

In [6]: ser['pedro']                                                            
Out[6]: 300
```